# Add discount to cart based on the option selected by user in the product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to have a "buy with exchange"  button next to add to cart option. That button then displays a selection box then based on which option is selected the discount have to be applied.
I did the following things in child theme function.php
 I created the button and selection box using the
 woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button action hook and placed  code for the selection box and "go" button next to it.
On pressing the go button i sent a post request to 
" admin-ajax.php" with the selected option and action.
The code in action function  is:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'getrequestexchange' );
function getrequestexchange(){

$exproduct = $_POST['eid'] ;
$dis=10;
switch($exproduct){
case "volvo":
        $dis=20;
        break;
case "saab":
    $dis=50;
    break;
default:
    $dis=300;
        break;


}

echo $dis;
die();


}
```

I want to add discount based on value of $dis .
I tried through the woocomerce_before_cart hook but couldn't  do it . can any one tell me another way to go about it.

Comment: The `$dis=10;` in your code will be ignored as the `switch...case default`: will cause $dis to either be: 20, 50 or 300.